# why return in if and else not working

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I have a very simple doubt. I am trying two processes to comm using named pipes. It's working fine but as I press n for ans, it's not executing return of main. but printing "RECEIVED From the CHILD : " which is in the PARENT PROCESS.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<wait.h>
#define NP1 "/tmp/np1"
#define NP2 "/tmp/np2"
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE    255
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int rdfd, wrfd, ret_val, count, numread;
    char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
    char ans;
    char cp[50];
    pid_t pid;

    ret_val = mkfifo(NP1,0666);
    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit (1);
    }
    ret_val = mkfifo(NP2, 0666);
    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit (1);
    }
    printf("\nSEND SOMETHING TO PARENT PROCESS\t");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&ans);

    pid=fork();
    if (pid==-1) {
        printf("\nERROR IN PID");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (ans=='y' || ans=='Y') {
        if (pid!=0) {
            //PARENT PROCESS
            /* Open the first named pipe for reading */
            rdfd = open(NP1, O_RDONLY);
            numread = read(rdfd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE);
            buf[numread] = '\0';
            printf("RECEIVED From the CHILD : %s\n", buf);

            /* Convert to the string to upper case */
            count = 0;
            while (count < numread) {
                buf[count] = toupper(buf[count]);
                count++;
            }

            wrfd = open(NP2, O_WRONLY);

            /* Write the converted string back to the second pipe */
            write(wrfd, buf, strlen(buf));
        } else {
            //CHILD PROCESS
            printf("\nEnter data to be sent to PARENT\t");
            fgets(cp, 50, stdin);
            wrfd = open(NP1, O_WRONLY);
            /* Write to the pipe */
            write(wrfd, cp, strlen(cp)+1);
            /* Open the second named pipe for reading */
            rdfd = open(NP2, O_RDONLY);
            /* Read from the pipe */
            numread = read(rdfd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE);
            buf[numread] = '\0';
            printf("RECEIVED From the PARENT : %s\n", buf);
            printf("\nSEND SOMETHING TO PARENT PROCESS\t");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",&ans);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix the formatting, please. It's such a pain to read this code...

Comment: the return will not work because if ans == 'n' your outer while itself not executing...

Comment: probably u need to ask for input in child and parent again and then store it ans and then compare it with 'n'

Comment: @TrilokM no no. What's the use of asking in both. It's always child who is initiating and sending string to parent. And as I am pressing 'n' when it asks "SEND SOMETHING TO PARENT PROCESS" , I am getting one more msg "RECEIVED From the CHILD :" which is in PARENT.

Comment: however it should just return to main

Comment: in such case, the outer loop doesn't execute, why are you confused, use another variable right...?

Comment: how? and why it's not working? I want it to end and show the command prompt as user press 'n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is when u give n as input to the child, the parent is still alive so in order to kill the parent use return from the read in parent to see if the child has exited or not and then if the child is already exit, then exit the parent too. this can be done by editing your code with
`if( (numread = read(rdfd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE)) == 0)
    return 0;`

actually once you give n as input in the child, the child exits and then old value of ans which is y is compared in parent process and so it doesn't exit....

check n reply... thanks...

Comment: I want it to be blocked for communication to happen. This will not server me my main purpose.

Comment: just check, it won't will server your purpose.

Comment: not working. Tried it. parent is not blocking for child to write. however it have to. because whatever child will enter, it will convert that to uppercase.

Comment: what have declared for NP1, NP2 and errno...?

Comment: that's just tmp/np1 and tmp/np2 . and errno here means??

Comment: yes sir. Now it's working. Thanks a lot..:) but I am really quite curious to know why main's return not working?? any idea!! Why parent process was not terminating?

Comment: actually once u give n as input in the child, the child exits and then old value of ans which is y is compared in parent process and so it doesn't exit....

Answer (score 0):

I think `while(ans=='y' || ans=='Y')` you code, So in that loop following code is worthless, just return form main.

```
 if(ans=='n')
     return(0); //NOT WORKING
```

**UPDATE**

Your problem looks for sharing variable between `child` and `parents`

Each process has its own memory space. A process can't normally access another process's memory.

In the case of fork, the `child` process's memory space starts as an exact copy of the parents. That includes variables, code, etc. Changing any of these in one will not change any similar variable in the othe

So here `ans` variable you modified in `child` which never affect in `parent` process. So can make some `kill` routine to terminate when `n` you press. Add following code in your child block after `scanf` function

```
        if(ans=='n' || ans == 'N')
        {
           printf("going to exit communication:\n");
           kill(pid, SIGTERM);  
        }
```

Comment: just check the program by first giving 'n' at the beginning

Comment: Then it's returning. I have checked it

Comment: @user3436838 Not causing issue for me.

Comment: but not working for me... Enter any input once and then press 'n'  . It's not working for me then.

Comment: @user3436838 can you give whole source regarding headers and macros.

Comment: only header files were not there. I have edited my code and shown them now.

Comment: @user3436838 so you want end while loop when user enter `n` right?

Comment: thanks . I have got my prog working. but i think instead of pid, i would need to use getppid and then kill that.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",&ans);
```

why you are using so much formatting may be this is the problem, to avoid new line problem we just put data

```
scanf(" %c",&ans);
```

another reason it is two different process and another one is waiting for read and you are trying to writing or opposite may be again problem. Some string and char reading creates problem I face this one and to avoid this I use different input functions e.g. for string puts and gets etc.

Comment: scanf(" %c",&ans); was not working.. that's why I used the first one.